# Strange results from 2 SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Query #1:

```
SELECT SUM(size) 
FROM RepoSize s 
LEFT JOIN VirtualRepo v ON s.repo_id = v.repo_id 
WHERE v.repo_id IS NULL;

+----------------+
| SUM(size)      |
+----------------+
| 61550890457198 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.32 sec)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT SUM(size) 
FROM RepoSize 
WHERE repo_id NOT IN (SELECT repo_id FROM VirtualRepo);

+----------------+
| SUM(size)      |
+----------------+
| 61551148262106 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.45 sec)
```

I thought the 2 SQL queries would return the same result, but the truth is the second value is larger than the first, `repo_id` is the primary key in both tables.

table structure:

```
mysql> desc RepoSize;
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| repo_id | char(37)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| size    | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| head_id | char(41)            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc VirtualRepo;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| repo_id     | char(36) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| origin_repo | char(36) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| path        | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| base_commit | char(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What **concrete RDBMS** are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Please provide the sample data.

Comment: Result(sum) may differ depending on the data in both tables.

Comment: I can't access the database and provide the data for now.. but can the data itself influence the result?

Comment: `ON s.repo_id = v.repo_id WHERE v.repo_id IS NULL;` looks scary to me. Basically you're comparing NULL with NULL and this probably gets into mode settings. Also `=` comparison differs from `IN`, especially if you're doing this comparing chars, and chars differing in length at that...

Comment: `can the data itself influence the result?`  yes it does.

Comment: What does `comparing NULL with NULL` mean? Am I comparing `v.repo_id` with NULL? @Ultimater

Comment: What results do you get when using NOT EXISTS   ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to build the sql with NOT EXISTS

Comment: Ah, sorry. The NULL part is fine. The difference here is `NOT IN` vs `=` behavior. Not sure why they would differ...

Comment: Any chance you can debug this by creating two more tables `EqualsTable` and `NotInTable`? Then use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT RepoSize.repo_id FROM ...` syntax and log the ids where the two differ?

Comment: Maybe I made a big mistake.. I got the result from my workmate and the data may has changed between two queries!  I have to run the sqls later by myself...

Answer (score 0):

As repo_id is primary key in both the tables, there is not a possibility of difference because of nulls in the field. So ideally both the queries should give the same result unless the data has changed in between the execution. So most probably the difference is because of change in data in between.